# Java using TWO different enum classes under the same name: possible?

Tags: java, interface, enums, extends

To start, I do have a "global" solution: rewrite the code. The problem is contextual.

I have few utility classes which are using an enum type like this:

```
for (NamedConfigEnum config : NamedConfigEnum.values())
```

and probably other enum class specific methods.

Where the class is simply an enum:

```
public enum NamedConfigEnum{...}
```

And of course imported as:

```
import package.NamedConfigEnum;
```

Now I want to define a second "fully equivalent" enum  type which has indeed values for a test environment. Namely one enum should be used for testing and one enum should be used for development.

My task is to to use one enum or the other without changing the utility classes, with the constraint that they both should compile. I am using maven, but I cannot really make some profile dependency as I still want the tests, while in development, to run with the "test enum".

I searched anything and everything from enum instantiation, subclassing, interface, but I could not find a real solution.

By "interfacing" the classes, the compiler seems to loose track of specific enum methods.. just like indeed .values().

Just to be clear, the constraint I have is on the utility classes and the enum classes (content), but nothing forbid me to rename the enums and create for example an interface like:

```
public interface NamedConfigEnum{...}
```

this would be "possible", but this simply doesn't work.

I think the problem might be general, i.e. reusing some libraries and code. And in particular it would suggest to be very careful while using emuns in java and it seems they are pretty special objects (if at all object ;) ).

Honestly I am a bit hopeless, but at least would like an answer like: this is a know problem in java ;)

On request I will put the very long list of stackoverflow similar/related question, but you can just google it.

The main issues I have found are:

- All enums implicitly extend java.lang.Enum. Since Java does not support multiple inheritance, an enum cannot extend anything else.
- Note that it is not possible to do a switch with this interface, then. (Or in general have a switch with an object which could come from more than one enum). [mine: then even iterate on values?]

This two are the main, which made failing any my attempt.

Thanks!
F

Comment: Classic XY problem. Don't write special test code. Test the real code. Otherwise you have to test the special test code, ...

Comment: Yeah, this is definitely an XY problem. Take a step back: why is this an enum in the first place? Why do you need to switch on it? Why do you need different enum values for test? More likely than not, your design went awry earlier, and now you've painted yourself into a corner -- rather than looking for the answer for this specific problem (which is basically unsolvable given the constraints you've outlined), help us help you find a solution to your *real* problem.

Comment: Yes.. and not ;) as I mentioned, I have the "solution", i.e. rewrite the full code as you indeed suggest. But my problem is right now within this context, i.e. I do not want to rewrite the code as at present it is an "external" library. Then of course I am considering to restructure the full thing.

Comment: And about tests, of course there will be the tests for the application. But in this particular case, I also want to set up an additional test suite which will test all the features of a library even if they are not yet used within my application. In other words this should grant the developers that the library is working and they can use in the near future all the features within a particular version. Kind of testing ahead...

Comment: Maybe I can add the full story. Which is this git: https://github.com/jaibeermalik/elasticsearch-tutorial

Comment: Maybe I can add the full story as it is fully open source. Which is this git: https://github.com/jaibeermalik/elasticsearch-tutorial. It has this enum defined: ElasticSearchIndexConfig and for example this service: SetupIndexService. So the idea is to use the tutorial as a complete test suite for elasticsearch (whatever version), and indeed to add specific tests for my application (the second enum). As the Author is better then me in both elasticsearch and java, I would try at present the least "refactoring".

Comment: I understand.. here the X problem might be: speak to the author ;)